# "..., ready to swoop at any moment." Grammarticallity in this context

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

Today I found a sentence:

> The eagle hovered, **ready to swoop at any moment.**

I don't know the grammarticallity of the sentence.

Can I rewrite as:

> The eagle hovered **and ready to swoop at any moment?**

What's the grammarticallity of the first sentence?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think "ready to swoop at any moment" is an adjectival phrase and it works as a complement.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is fine.  “ready to swoop at any moment“ is taking the place of an adjective or another simple sentence.

Compare:
The eagle hovered and it was brown.
The eagle hovered, brown.

The eagle hovered, ready to swoop at any moment.
The eagle hovered and it was ready to swoop at any moment.

You cannot rewrite as above (in your second sentence).

This sentence is telling you what the eagle was.

In order to agree with the first part you should use “and was ready...” or “and it was ready...”.